# Compare two strings and if they are equal backwards

Tags: c

Lets say we got two inputs. One being 123 and one being 321. Now, these two should return True.

Another eg. 543 with 345.

This is how far I've gotten:

```
int a,i=0;

printf("condition value");
scanf("%d",&i);

printf("comparison value");
scanf("%d",&a);

a=a%10;
i=a/10;

if(a==i){
   printf("\nTrue");
}
```

Has anyone got any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: strings? or numbers?

Comment: do you want to treat the input as integer or string?

Comment: Why not read as a string and compare then.. It will be easier..

Comment: Compare characters of strings, without parsing them into integers.

Comment: as an integer. hence why i've done the scanf's as digits(%d) :)

Comment: @Joel: clarify also this: Another eg. 12321, please

Comment: @Giorgi that's called a palindrome. it is equal to itself as 12321, the reverse of that is 12321. but that was just an example. i'll scratch that from the question.

Comment: @Joel: I see but you said there was two input

Comment: yes. the first scanf.
And the second scanf :) if the 1st scanf 123, and in the second scanf 321. the return value should be true.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz there you go.

Comment: So does `210` and input `21` both compare equally to `12`?

Comment: @Joel  your format is somewhat better, but you forgot to indent the content between {} in the if condition. I've edited your question. Consistent indentation and formatting is very important as it helps to keep your code readable (for others and especially for you).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to know whether one string matches the reverse of another string, just compare character-by-character.  Even if it's guaranteed that all the characters are digits, it's *easier* to solve the problem in the string domain.

Even if there's some number-theory trickery that would give you a closed-form solution for fixed-size integers, parsing strings into `int` in the first place will be slower than just a character-compare loop.

Often you can make your code simpler by taking advantage of limitations on the input, but it looks like this isn't one of those cases.

Comment: <disclaimer>I'm not the downvoter</disclaimer> Because it doesn't provide a copy/pastable solution?

Answer (score 0):

Given OP wants to check integers based on this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758917/compare-two-strings-and-if-they-are-equal-backwards/33761975#comment55285281_33758917)

Simply reverse the digits of one of the numbers

Remove the least-significant digit from `x`, one at a time.  Use that value to build up the reverse of `x`.  Note that the range of the "reverse of x" is wider than the range of `unsigned`.

Use `unsigned` to avoid sign issues.

```
unsigned long long unsigned_rev(unsigned x) {
  unsigned long long rev = 0;
  while (x) {
    rev = rev*10 + x%10;
    x /= 10;
  }
  return rev;
}
```